# Does presentViewController change view.frame?

Tags: objective-c

I hava a question about screen transition.

To transit a screen, I often use presentViewController method.

```
NextViewController *nextViewController = [[NextViewController alloc] init];
nextViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(10, 10, 200, 400);    
[self presentViewController:nextViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

However, the view.frame setting that I implemented is not applied.

Following code runs correctly.

```
NextViewController *nextViewController = [[NextViewController alloc] init];
[self presentViewController:nextViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
nextViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(10, 10, 200, 400);
```

What's the difference of these code?
Is view.frame redefined in presentViewController method?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
NextViewController *nextViewController = [[NextViewController alloc] init];
nextViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(10, 10, 200, 400);    
[self presentViewController:nextViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

The above code is not working because you are setting the view of nextViewController which not yet created.

so in your next code you load the view controller first and then change the frame of the loaded view.

=========================EDIT===========================

If you want to set the frame in the view controller directly then bind your view with a `IBOutlet` and then in

```
- (void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
 {
      //set the frame here
      self.myView.frame = CGRectMake(10, 10, 200, 400);
 }
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: But, I can't set view.frame in NextViewController, as follows. [super viewDidLoad]; self.view.frame = CGRectMake(10, 10, 200, 400);

Comment: If I am not getting you wrong then u are setting the frame in viewDidLoad function??

Comment: I tried both ways. "nextViewController.view.frame" in rootViewController, and "self.view.frame" after "[super viewDidLoad];" in nextViewController.

Comment: did you bind your view to any IBOutlet?

Answer (score 1):

self.view is not created before presenting the view controller.

ie) nextViewController.view.frame is not valid before [self presentViewController:nextViewController animated:YES completion:nil];

Answer (score 0):

Present the `nextViewController` and then only you can update its various properties. Doing it before the view has been loaded into the view will fail to occur. Present the view,then update it.